# Table numbering

Tags: tables

I have made a table (eg revision history) that I do not want to include in my table numbering in my table of contents. 
The second table now receives number 2 in my list of tables. But I want to change this table in to table number 1.

In other words, how can I start the numbering of Tables starting from Table 2 (=1)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: just use a plain text paragraph  not a `\caption` in the first `table` and it will not be numbered or listed. (or use `\caption*` from  the caption package)

Comment: The table could be a longtable, in which case the counter is stepped. Nobody knows.